# How do I create namespaced models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to create namespaced model like:

```
rails g model aaa
rails g model aaa/bbb
rails g model aaa/ccc
```

When I run `rails g model aaa/bbb`, Rails will auto-generate:

```
module AAA
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'aaa_'
  end
end
```

`AAA` is also a model, so I need put that in the module:

```
Module AAA
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'staff_'
  end

  class AAA < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

but that does not work. When I run `AAA.new`, Rails says:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for AAA:Module
```

How do I instantiate this model?

Comment: Try using `AAA::AAA.new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only call `new` on `class`es, and you've nested an `AAA::AAA` class inside your `AAA` module. You either need to call `AAA::AAA.new` or not wrap the class in the module. Even if you make `AAA` a top-level class instead of a module, you can still nest `AAA::BBB` inside it. That would look like this:

```
class AAA < ActiveRecord::Base
  class BBB < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

Then you can call both `AAA.new` and `AAA::BBB.new`.

Comment: Can I direct call `AAA` instead `AAA::AAA`? If I'm not put the __AAA class__ in the __AAA Module__ Rails will says that `TypeError: Staff is not a class`. and Thank's ur help! My question after you reformat clearer than me.

Comment: You can only call `new` on classes, and `AAA` in you code is a module, so no, you can not call `AAA.new` directly. You must either call `AAA::AAA.new` or make `AAA` a class.

Answer (score 0):

We've always done namespacing like this:

```
#app/models/aaa/model.rb
class Aaa::Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   def new
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
Aaa::Model.new
```

---

If you're using a module, you may wish to use the following: http://www.benfranklinlabs.com/where-to-put-rails-modules/

```
#app/lib/aaa.rb
module Aaa
   def self.table_name_prefix
      'aaa_'
   end
end

#app/models/aaa/aaa.rb
class Aaa::Aaa < ActiveRecord::Base
   def new
   end
end
```

You'd still have to call `Aaa::Aaa.new`